# angular + .netcore. до контролера не доходит запрос с клиента

Tags: .net, angular, .net-core

Решил воспользоваться помощью генератора кода NSwagStudio.
Написал WebApi, подключил nuget-пакет NSwag, на основе сгенерированного json файла приложение создало ts файл.
Вот только моих знаний не очень хватает понять, что в коде происходит.
Вот, например, вызываю данный метод (тот который **deleteCustomer**)

```js
    deleteCustomer(id: string | null): Observable<Customer> {
        let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/Customers/{id}";
        if (id === undefined || id === null)
            throw new Error("The parameter 'id' must be defined.");
        url_ = url_.replace("{id}", encodeURIComponent("" + id));
        url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");

        let options_ : any = {
            observe: "response",
            responseType: "blob",
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                "Accept": "application/json"
            })
        };
        return this.http.request("delete", url_, options_).pipe(_observableMergeMap((response_ : any) => {
            return this.processDeleteCustomer(response_);
        })).pipe(_observableCatch((response_: any) => {
            if (response_ instanceof HttpResponseBase) {
                try {
                    return this.processDeleteCustomer(<any>response_);
                } catch (e) {
                    return <Observable<Customer>><any>_observableThrow(e);
                }
            } else
                return <Observable<Customer>><any>_observableThrow(response_);
        }));
    }

    protected processDeleteCustomer(response: HttpResponseBase): Observable<Customer> {
        const status = response.status;
        const responseBlob =
            response instanceof HttpResponse ? response.body :
            (<any>response).error instanceof Blob ? (<any>response).error : undefined;

        let _headers: any = {}; if (response.headers) { for (let key of response.headers.keys()) { _headers[key] = response.headers.get(key); }};
        if (status === 200) {
            return blobToText(responseBlob).pipe(_observableMergeMap(_responseText => {
            let result200: any = null;
            let resultData200 = _responseText === "" ? null : JSON.parse(_responseText, this.jsonParseReviver);
            result200 = Customer.fromJS(resultData200);
            return _observableOf(result200);
            }));
        } else if (status !== 200 && status !== 204) {
            return blobToText(responseBlob).pipe(_observableMergeMap(_responseText => {
            return throwException("An unexpected server error occurred.", status, _responseText, _headers);
            }));
        }
        return _observableOf<Customer>(<any>null);
    }
```

проблема в том, что запрос на бек не доходит, а именно вот в этой строчке

`return this.http.request("delete", url_, options_).pipe(_observableMergeMap((response_ : any) => { return this.processDeleteCustomer(response_);`

выполнение завершается. Пробовал посылать этот же запрос через web форму nswag (которая url_adress_backend:port/swagger), там по данному url все работает.

настройки для Cors в приложении следующие

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
            .AllowCredentials();
        });
```